Japanese Artsy Cursive Fonts for Shogi
I've just created a adaptation of my Go (board game) package — which was only possible thanks to this community — for shogi, which you can find here: @psygo/latex_shogi.

Although that's fine, I think it could be more pleasant to have the font be something more cursive, like what you see in real pieces typically. I personally like lishogi's default font quite a bit, although the white drops inside some of the strokes are not to my liking.
Is there a Japanese font package in LaTeX with that sort of cursive font? I think finding a font file, installing it on my Mac/PC and then using \setmainfont{<font>} should also be enough.
Here's an example from Wikipedia of a cursive font on a piece:

And here's the code for generating that sample — by the way, does anybody know why using width or height on the \draw (...) grid (...) line doesn't work as expected? —:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

% ~A6 (+ 5mm min left and right offset)
\usepackage[%
  paperheight   = 148mm, 
  paperwidth    = 105mm,
  bindingoffset = 5mm,
  left          = 5mm,
  right         = 8mm,
  top           = 15.2mm,
  bottom        = 13.2mm,
  footskip      = 6.35mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{luatexja}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{%
  /phili/shogiban/.cd, 
    board dimension/.store in   = \boardDimension,
    board dimension             = 5 cm,
    height multiplier/.store in = \heightMultiplier,
    height multiplier           = 1.2,
}

\newcommand{\calculateDimensions}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{\boardDimension}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\height}{\boardDimension * \heightMultiplier}
}

\newcommand{\calculateSteps}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\stepX}{\width / 9 cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\stepY}{\height / 9 cm}
}
    
\newcommand{\shogiGrid}[1][]{
  \draw[xstep = \stepX, ystep = \stepY]
    (0, 0) grid
    (\boardDimension, \boardDimension * \heightMultiplier); % why can't I seem to be able to use `\width` and `\height` here???
}

\newenvironment{shogiban}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/phili/shogiban/.cd, #1}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \calculateDimensions
    \calculateSteps

    \shogiGrid
}{
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\pgfkeys{%
  /phili/piece/.cd, 
    x/.store in     = \pieceX,
    x               = 0,
    y/.store in     = \pieceY,
    y               = 0,
    text/.store in  = \pieceText,
    text            = A,
    color/.store in = \pieceColor,
    text            = black,
}

\newcommand{\piece}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/phili/piece/.cd, #1}
  
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceCorrectedX}{(\pieceX + 0.5) * \stepX}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceCorrectedY}{(\pieceY + 0.5) * \stepY}

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceBaseStartX}{(\pieceX + 0.2) * \stepX}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceBaseStartY}{(\pieceY + 0.2) * \stepY}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceBaseEndX}{(\pieceX + 0.8) * \stepX}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceBaseEndY}{(\pieceY + 0.2) * \stepY}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceTopLeftX}{(\pieceX + 0.22) * \stepX}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceTopLeftY}{(\pieceY + 0.73) * \stepY}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceTopRightX}{(\pieceX + 0.78) * \stepX}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceTopRightY}{(\pieceY + 0.73) * \stepY}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceTopX}{(\pieceX + 0.5) * \stepX}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceTopY}{(\pieceY + 0.85) * \stepY}

  \draw [draw = \pieceColor]
    (\pieceTopX, \pieceTopY) --
    (\pieceTopLeftX, \pieceTopLeftY) --
    (\pieceBaseStartX, \pieceBaseStartY) --
    (\pieceBaseEndX, \pieceBaseEndY) --
    (\pieceTopRightX, \pieceTopRightY) --
    (\pieceTopX, \pieceTopY);

  \draw (\pieceCorrectedX, \pieceCorrectedY) 
    node[
      font  = \fontsize{7.5pt}{7.5pt}\selectfont,
      color = \pieceColor,
    ] {\pieceText};
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{shogiban}[board dimension = 5cm]
    % Back Line
    \piece[x = 0, y = 0, text = 香, color = black] % Lance
    \piece[x = 1, y = 0, text = 桂, color = black] % Knight
    \piece[x = 2, y = 0, text = 銀, color = black] % Silver
    \piece[x = 3, y = 0, text = 金, color = black] % Gold
    \piece[x = 4, y = 0, text = 玉, color = black] % King (sente)
    \piece[x = 5, y = 0, text = 金, color = black] % Gold
    \piece[x = 6, y = 0, text = 銀, color = black] % Silver
    \piece[x = 7, y = 0, text = 桂, color = black] % Knight
    \piece[x = 8, y = 0, text = 香, color = black] % Lance
    % Middle Line
    \piece[x = 1, y = 1, text = 角, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 7, y = 1, text = 飛, color = black] % Bishop
    % Front Line
    \piece[x = 0, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 1, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 2, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 3, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 4, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 5, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 6, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 7, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    \piece[x = 8, y = 2, text = 歩, color = black] % Bishop
    % Promoted Pieces
    \piece[x = 1, y = 3, text = 馬, color = red] % Promoted Bishop (Dragon Horse)
    \piece[x = 7, y = 3, text = 龍, color = red] % Promoted Rook (Dragon King)
    \piece[x = 3, y = 3, text = 全, color = red] % Promoted Silver (Gold)
    \piece[x = 4, y = 3, text = 今, color = red] % Promoted Knight
    \piece[x = 5, y = 3, text = 杏, color = red] % Promoted Lance
    \piece[x = 4, y = 4, text = と, color = red] % Promoted Pawn
  \end{shogiban}
\end{document}
  \end{shogiban}
\end{document}

If you happen to adapt this into drawing the 2-line version of the pieces, I would be very thankful as well.

Maybe this one: https://www.freekanjifonts.com/japanesefont-hakusyu-gyosho-download/ ... this one is close, but not free: https://en.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/2550

The control sequences \depth, \width and \height are used by common packages. It might be wise to use other names.

I would do two things which will simplify everything enormously:

Use \pics (If you don't like the syntax, you can still put it in some other command).
Adjust the x and y of the whole tikzpicture environment at once.

It seems not too easy to find a freely usable Japanese calligraphic font. For the example below I used Yuji Mai Regular which can be found on Google Fonts, but it is maybe not quite what you are looking for.
If you want to make a package from this, it might be a nice idea to use some unified prefix for your commands.
Anyways, if you set x and y, you don't need to adjust all the single positions and sizes of the grid and the pieces, as the underlying coordinate grid has already been resized as required:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\shogifont{YujiMai-Regular}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{
  /tikz/pics/shogi grid/.style={
    code={
      \draw (0, 0) grid[step = 1] 
        (\shogiBoardDimension, \shogiBoardDimension * \shogiHeightMultiplier); 
    },
  },
  /tikz/pics/shogi piece/.style={
    code={
      \pgfkeys{/phili/shogiban/piece/.cd, #1}
      \draw[draw = \shogiPieceColor]
        (0.5, 0.85) --
        (0.22, 0.73) --
        (0.2, 0.2) --
        (0.8, 0.2) --
        (0.78, 0.73) --
        cycle;
      \node[
        font  = \fontsize{7.5 pt}{7.5 pt}\selectfont\shogifont,
        color = \shogiPieceColor,
      ] at (0.5, 0.5) {\shogiPieceText};
    }
  },
  /phili/shogiban/.cd, 
    board dimension/.store in   = \shogiBoardDimension,
    board dimension             = 5 cm,
    height multiplier/.store in = \shogiHeightMultiplier,
    height multiplier           = 1.2,
    initial scale/.style        = {
      /tikz/x                   = \shogiBoardDimension / 9 cm * 1 cm,
      /tikz/y                   = \shogiBoardDimension * \shogiHeightMultiplier / 9 cm * 1 cm
    },
    piece/color/.store in       = \shogiPieceColor, 
    piece/color                 = black,
    piece/text/.store in        = \shogiPieceText,
    piece/text                  = A
}

\newenvironment{shogiban}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[/phili/shogiban/.cd, #1, initial scale]
    \pic{shogi grid};
}{
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{shogiban}[board dimension = 5 cm]

  \pic at (0, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 香}}; % Lance
  \pic at (1, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 桂}}; % Knight
  \pic at (2, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 銀}}; % Silver
  \pic at (3, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 金}}; % Gold
  \pic at (4, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 玉}}; % King (sente)
  \pic at (5, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 金}}; % Gold
  \pic at (6, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 銀}}; % Silver
  \pic at (7, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 桂}}; % Knight
  \pic at (8, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 香}}; % Lance

  \pic at (1, 1) {shogi piece = {text = 角}}; % Bishop
  \pic at (7, 1) {shogi piece = {text = 飛}}; % Bishop

  \foreach \x in {0, ..., 8} {
    \pic at (\x, 2) {shogi piece = {text = 歩}}; % Pawn  
  }

  \pic at (1, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 馬}}; % Promoted Bishop (Dragon Horse)
  \pic at (7, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 龍}}; % Promoted Rook (Dragon King)
  \pic at (3, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 全}}; % Promoted Silver (Gold)
  \pic at (4, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 今}}; % Promoted Knight
  \pic at (5, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 杏}}; % Promoted Lance
  \pic at (4, 4) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = と}}; % Promoted Pawn

  \end{shogiban}
\end{document}



Thank you for the code improvements and suggestions! I like that font much more, except for that と (to). It's gonna take a little while for me to get back to that project, when I do, I'll come back to this question.

One of my questions about \pics and TikZ nodes, for this use case, would be: I was thinking about adding a scale parameter to the pieces, since it's common for them to be differentiated through their sizes as well. But, if I do it as is, the letters will be ok, but the piece itself will not be centered anymore. How would I do it with \pics?

@psygo An idea could be to first set the origin of the pic to the center of the relevant cell of the board and the create the pic in such a way that its center sits at the origin. Currently, the origin is at the lower left border of the relevant cell. Transformations are relative to the origin per default.

I've created a separate question for it.

I know answer with links is usually not preferred. But I still want to give some suggestions. I believe that most of chinese font will cover most of the word on the pieces. If you know Chinese, there is a website (https://www.fonts.net.cn/) contain a lot of non-commercial free to use fonts. Most of them are true type font.
Here is an example using fish stone cursive font (https://www.fonts.net.cn/font-34175359167.html?previewText=%E9%A6%99%E6%A1%82%E9%8A%80%E9%87%91%E7%8E%8B%E8%A7%92%E9%A3%9B%E6%AD%A9%E6%9D%8F%E4%BB%8A%E5%85%A8%E9%A6%AC%E9%BE%8D%E3%81%A8):
Here is the results in overleaf:

https://www.overleaf.com/8968646833txvscgsvtmkz#e374e8
